# Match and count in a vacation tracking sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My team has a vacation tracking calendar in Google Sheets. I'm trying to create a formula (for the red cells) to automatically count the number of days entered in the calendar by person and absence code.

[image]

I've tried a number of different ways to solve this using Countifs, Match and Index but it only works for a single range, yet I need to count one range for each month of the year.

Is there an easier way to do this than adding 12 similar formulas together.

Comment: Welcome! I didn't understand: you need to calculate monthly or yearly? If monthly, where would that range be replicated?

Comment: What's the difference between Personal Well-Being and Vacation? Asking for a friend...

Comment: @Martín Looking to calculate YTD days booked only

Comment: @pgSystemTester They are the same as vacation days, but they are part of our flex benefits. Each employee can choose whether they want extra days off (taxable) or exchange those days for the same $$s in a tax-free health spending account.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need a spill range you could just do a basic countif off of a filtered range on the name.

so if your data starts on A8 and goes all the way to column `f` (you'd want more), and you put the exact string you're searching above the cell in row 3, this should work:

```
=countif(filter($A$8:$F,$A$8:$A=$C3),D$2)
```

Here's [a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wrQ3LVWDh7LSs7Faraa0uVxCdJWkOAAzN_wcK8ZwrMo/edit?usp=sharing) from screen shot.

[image]